# Powershell CSV removing newline from last cell

Tags: .net, powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I have a CSV file that is in the format below:

```
ID,Name,Notes,Status
1,aaa,blah,
blah2,status1
2,bbb,foo,status1
3,ccc,pow,
pow2,status1
```

As you can see, some of the cells in the Notes column contain a comma and newline character. I need to replace these characters with a space and aggregate the data in the new line into the Notes cell of the previous row, while still bringing the status into the Status column, so that it will look like this:

```
ID,Name,Notes,Status
1,aaa,blah blah2,status1
2,bbb,foo,status1
3,ccc,pow pow2,status1
```

I came up with the following snippet:

```
(Import-Csv $reportfile) | % {
  $_.Notes = $_.Notes -replace "`r`n",' '
  $_.Notes = $_.Notes -replace "`n",' '
  $_.Notes = $_.Notes -replace ',',' '
  $_
} | Export-Csv $newfile -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is that when the file is imported, the data which is on a line by itself is interpreted by Powershell as a row. So when I export it, it is still saved on its own row. Any ideas how I can import the file differently and still accomplish replacing those unwanted characters from that column?

Comment: `Import-Csv` reads a file and interprets it according to how CSV files work. If your file isn't a CSV file or violates RFC 4180 somehow, then things can get strange, of course. You can always pre-process the file's contents and pass them to `ConvertFrom-Csv`, though.

Comment: How can I pre-process the file and only touch those columns, without using Import-CSV?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
(Get-Content -ReadCount 0 $reportfile) -replace ',\r\n(?=\D)', ' ' -split "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

(untested)

This would first read the file as a single string, then replace a comma at the end of a line followed by a line break by a space, then splits the string at line breaks and passes it to `ConvertFrom-Csv`.